# Python: Find method to match similar but not identical names from two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, sequence

I have two data frames, one contains service requests opened by customers and the second contains orders by customers.
I want to merge these two data frames on customer name, but the problem is that the names are not identical because they came from two different sources.
Just a fictive example: data frame 1 can have "Facebook, Inc." and data frame 2 can be "facebook social media".

I tried using SequenceMatcher (from difflib import SequenceMatcher) and take the result with the highest ratio per customer in data frame 1 but the accuracy was not good enough.

I would be happy to hear ideas from people that encountered the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: try levenshtein-distance. see https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fuzzywuzzy` library or optimized Levenstein distance from `editdistance` package. Optimized Levenstein distance uses just two last rows instead of classical two-dimension matrix. In order to calculate similarity, use the next formula:

```
ratio = 1 - levenstein(a, b) / max(len(a), len(b))
```

Furthermore, you can use Damerau-Levenstein modification. It allows to calculate character transpositions instead of deletion/insertion operations.

https://pypi.org/project/pyxDamerauLevenshtein/

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful, I still struggle with this because I'm getting some incorrect matchings when the strings are getting too different, but perhaps this doesn't have an automated solution.